# Laravel Blade Form::select -- now forcing escape?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, html-escape-characters, laravelcollective

I've had this code running since L5.0.   With the latest update to L5.3.30 + the dependencies, it appears to be broken.  Perhaps I've done something wrong since the beginning?

Here is the simplified code:

```
    {!! Form::select('currency', ['USD'=>'USD: *escape code here*'], 
        null, ['class'=>'form-control', "required", 'id'=>'currency']) !!}
```

For the last few years this code has returned a select box with text like this:  "USD: $"

After composer update to L5.3.30, on all servers (test, dev, prod), it now returns the html symbol instead:  "USD: *escape code here*"

I have temporarily (and successfully) patched this using:

```
 <select name = 'currency' id="currency" required class="form-control">
       @foreach (\Helper::currency() as $k=>$v)
                  <option  value="{{$k}}">{!! $v !!}</option>
       @endforeach
 </select>
```

The above code has the escape code for the currency in the $v var, and shows up correctly in the select box.

Please help - this breaks quite a few forms on my app.

Thank you.

EDIT: I can still correctly display unescaped text using {!! !!} everywhere else.  It appears to only affect Form::select() items.  I therefore am starting to think this is not an issue with Laravel's blade escape, but rather with the latest version of the Laravel Collective Form function

SOLUTION: I noted this to the Laravel Collective Dev team, but this has apparently NOT been rolled back.  See https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/issues/296 for latest.

Comment: Yes it is indeed Laravelcollective Formbuilder issue. I tracked this issue down to file /vendor/laravelcollective/html/src/FormBuilder.php line 683, there is "$this->html->escapeAll($display)" which is causing issues. Maybe you can try to contact developers, they do listen to emails. Please keep us updated.

Comment: Wow.  An actual bug.  Thank you very much @Miloslav Milo Janoušek , I don't have to think I'm crazy any more.  I'll reach out to the dev team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "fix" it by downgrading Laravelcollective html package to version 5.3.0 (down from 5.3.1 which is current version). Just edit composer.json "require"

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.3.*",
```

with this:

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.3.0",
```

Downside is that you will use older version which may have some other issues which was already fixed in 5.3.1, but i dont have any specific information on that.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Really appreciate you hunting this for me, I couldn't see the forest through the trees.  Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the new syntax from Laravel 5.0. Just switching to {!! !!} is enough to fix using the form elements.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade

Blade Tag Changes

> For better security by default, Laravel 5.0 escapes all output from both the {{ }} and {{{ }}} Blade directives. A new {!! !!} directive has been introduced to display raw, unescaped output. The most secure option when upgrading your application is to only use the new {!! !!} directive when you are certain that it is safe to display raw output.
>
> However, if you must use the old Blade syntax, add the following lines at the bottom of  AppServiceProvider@register:

```
\Blade::setRawTags('{{', '}}');
\Blade::setContentTags('{{{', '}}}');
\Blade::setEscapedContentTags('{{{', '}}}');
```

> This should not be done lightly, and may make your application more vulnerable > to XSS exploits. Also, comments with {{-- will no longer work.

Comment: Thank you for the response Adam.  Yes, {!! !!} should work correctly, but this is the problem - it does not.

Comment: Do you have a clear error message? The forms package was removed from Laravel in 5.0. You may need to install the Laravel Collectives package, they took over the work. https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html

`"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"`

Comment: Hi @Adam.  No, there is no error.  Everything else works fine.  All other Form:: functions are working, including this one.  It's just forcing an escape when it shouldn't be.  The package is correct, and has been loaded as laravelcollective since they took over - it has been working fine.  IE no change to code -- just broken after update to latest version of Laravel / Collective.  I am wondering if anyone else can reproduce the issue in a Form::select with a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

following this issue https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/issues/296 and this commit https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/pull/297/files?diff=split ,

i changed line 683, ("$this->html->escapeAll()" to "e()" )

before

```
return $this->toHtmlString('<optgroup label="' . $this->html->escapeAll($label) . '">' . implode('', $html) . '</optgroup>');
```

after

```
return $this->toHtmlString('<optgroup label="' . e($label) . '">' . implode('', $html) . '</optgroup>');
```

it's worked for me, before the latest version be released.

Answer (score -1):

Instead using

```
{!! your code !!}
```

try using

```
{{ your code }}
```

`{!! !!}` is used to displaying Unescaped Data. From the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade)

> Displaying Unescaped Data
>
> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want
>   your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:
>
> Hello, {!! $name !!}.
>
> Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your
>   application. Always use the escaped, double curly brace syntax to
>   prevent XSS attacks when displaying user supplied data.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Gayan.  Using {{ }} will not display the $, it will display the HTML symbol.  The problem is that BOTH {{ }} AND {!! !!} are displaying the HTML symbol in the select box.  This was never the case prior to 5.3.30.  E.g.  {!! &nbsp; !!}} should display a space -- it does not now.